# How to build a GUI on top of RDF or OWL ontology

Tags: eclipse, gwt, rdf, jena, owl

I use Eclipse with the OWL API or Jena to load my ontology. I want to map instances from the ontology to clickable images or icons in a GUI so that the ontology can be visualized for human consumption.  I can create the interface with GWT Designer, but could anybody advise me on how to make certain parts of the interface link to instances from the ontology?

Comment: Have you create a GUI with GWT before? If not you should do that before https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/ Otherwise please specify your question: what have you tried? Where are your problems? It's hard to give general advices in such a field.

Comment: ...why did you use the word `ontology` so many times?

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I understand now, I will get my details together and repost. I really like the word 'ontology' this is why i have used it so many times.

Comment: @gray Did you ever figure out a solution for visualizing ontologies?

Comment: I ended up using jOWL: http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/

Comment: Questions asking for libraries and tools are generally off-topic on stack overflow.  However, since the question hasn't been closed, you (@gray) should post your comment as an answer and accept it, both to let others know that it was useful for you, and to help reduce the number of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used jOWL library: [jOWL](http://jowl.ontologyonline.org/)